# How to deal with missing binary dependent variable?

Tags: categorical-data, data-transformation, dataset, simulation, missing-data

Consider the below scenario.

llegal immigrant behavior: Suppose you want to interdict with illegal immigrants to catch them enter a country. Let say they wait/observe some certain condition set X (e.g., patrol schedule(if known somehow), hour of the day, day of the week, weather conditions, etc.) to move and pass the border. X can be observed both by you and the immigrants. Let Y be the immigrants' action: 1, if they try; 0, otherwise. Apparently, Y is known by the immigrants, but you may not always be interdicting with them, so that you are uncertain about their action. Meaning that when you do not interdict/detect illegal border pass, you assume the corresponding Y is 0. However, there might (or may not) had been illegal passes that you do not know. In that case, you are uncertain about the target variable Y.

Here, I assume that the values where Y=0 are missing.

Then the question is:

- What are the available imputation or simulation methods?

Thanks.